# C++ lambdas, "error: expected expression"

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to reproduce java's streams API in C++, and have made this program so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename E>
class stream {
    virtual void collect(void (*consumer) (E)) = 0;
    virtual bool anyMatch(bool (*predicate) (E)) {
        bool found = false;
        collect([&found](E obj) -> { if (predicate(obj)) {found = true} });
        return found;
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile it with g++:

[image]

What am I doing wrong the lambda? It is supposed to provide a function (the consumer) which will test the given E with the predicate (a function), and if it yields true, set found to true.

Comment: This isn't lazy. One of the main advantages of streams over the standard algorithms (*cough* `std::accumulate`, `std::any_of`) is that they're lazy. There are already libraries for this, such as range-v3, which should become standard at some point.

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly just trying to learn c++

Comment: Only lambdas without captures are convertible to plain function pointers. A lambda with captures can't possibly do that - it wouldn't have a place to store those captures.

Comment: Is there another data type I can use to hold the capture lambda?

Comment: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: Asides from the other comments, your line with the lambda has (at least) three problems. Try this: `collect([&found, predicate](E obj) { if (predicate(obj)) {found = true;} });`

Comment: Have you specified a standard? At least `-std=c++11` is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to do it to learn C++

Comment: What is `obj`? Where is it coming from? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Obj is coming from an implementor of stream's collect method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few separate issues in your code:

1. The error you posted suggests that you're compiling in pre-C++11 mode. Lambdas were introduced in C++11.
2. There are several syntax errors. Your lambda trailing return type is missing the type, and you're missing a semicolon in the body of the lambda.
3. You're trying to convert a non-captureless lambda to a function pointer. This is impossible, as capturing variables requires a state/context.

---

Your code is not valid C++ - the syntax is incorrect. Here's [a version with valid syntax](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TkHIIXjQd1HSND9z):

```
template <typename E>
class stream
{
    virtual void collect(void (*consumer)(E)) = 0;
    virtual bool anyMatch(bool (*predicate)(E))
    {
        bool found = false;
        collect([predicate, &found](E obj)
            {
                if(predicate(obj))                    
                    found = true;                    
            });

        return found;
    }
};
```

Nevertheless, the code will not compile because **non-captureless lambdas cannot be converted to function pointers**. If that was allowed, it would be a recipe for disaster, as the information regarding the captured variables will be lost. [You can instead use `std::function`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Pv3ydZDWic1ykcjQ), which erases the type of the lambda and works with non-empty capture lists, at the cost of memory/run-time overhead:

```
template <typename E>
class stream
{
    virtual void collect(std::function<void(E)> consumer)
    {
        (void)consumer;
    }

    virtual bool anyMatch(std::function<bool(E)> predicate)
    {
        bool found = false;
        collect([predicate, &found](E obj)
            {
                if(predicate(obj))                    
                    found = true;                    
            });

        return found;
    }
};
```

Comment: It only compiles because you never actually instantiate `stream`. [Once you do, it fails](http://rextester.com/LYRBD37125).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: yeah - by "it compiles" I meant "correct/parseable C++ syntax". I will clarify the answer

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I improved the answer. Let me know if it's still misleading

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: [it does](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rP1k6hOdRWmkQrpY). `[](int obj) -> { (void) obj; }` is not valid lambda syntax - he forgot the return type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit also, `if (predicate(obj)) {found = true}` is not valid syntax either. A semicolon is missing after `found = true`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I have no idea why I wrote that